# UIKit: How can i resize a Viewcontroller to fit splitview primary column?

Tags: swift, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, calendarkit

In my UIKit App i am using a `UISplitViewController()` as my rootViewController. I configure it in my `SceneDelegate` like this:

```swift
var splitView: UISplitViewController?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    self.makeSplitViewController()
    
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = self.splitView
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        self.splitView?.viewController(for: .secondary)?.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }
}

func makeSplitViewController() {
    let splitViewController = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary
    
    let primaryViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CalendarViewController())
    let secondaryViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: EventDetailView())
    
    splitViewController.setViewController(primaryViewController, for: .primary)
    splitViewController.setViewController(secondaryViewController, for: .secondary)
    splitViewController.setViewController(primaryViewController, for: .compact)
    
    self.splitView = splitViewController
}
```

As you can see, i am using the `CalendarViewController` (wrapped inside a UINavigationController) as my primaryViewController and for the secondary view i am using a SwiftUI View, wrapped in a `UIHostingController`

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the CalendarViewController fits the iPhone Screen but not the iPad Primary Column. The `CalendarViewController` comes from [CalendarKit](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit), a Swift Calendar Library.

What do i need to change in the CalendarViewController to fit the SplitView Primary Column? Any ideas?

Reference: [CalendarViewController](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarApp/blob/master/Calendar/CalendarViewController.swift)

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to size classes. On an iPad, the default (read: in full screen) the root VC is *always* going to be "Regular", where on an iPhone it will likely be "Compact" in portrait mode. My first idea is to test my hypothesis out - have you tried using your iPad in split screen? That should clear up where things are not what you want. Next, I'd recommend (attribute to @matt) https://www.biteinteractive.com/split-view-controllers-done-right-in-ios-14/ where he showed me how *best* to make my split VC *not* be the root. It's gives you more flexibility, period.

Comment: @dfd thanks for your answer. In Splitscreen, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwTiF.png 
for reference: https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/issues/320#issuecomment-932959922

Comment: I probably needed to be more specific, with regards to size classes. A `UISplitViewController` "obeys" what size class it's showing as of - I think - iOS 13. Keeping in mind that you are (a) using an iPad, (b) using some version of iPadOS [you've *not* said], and (c) at the moment your two screenshots show "primary/secondary" [I think] and what I'll call "half/half" on "an iPad" [iPad mini? iPad pro 12.9 inch?, something else?] it's hard to actually duplicate. More, keep in mind that part of the question uses an Apple app [Calendar] that...???

Comment: @dfd sorry, i am using an iPad Pro 11 inch with iPadOS 15. Would it help you if I created a repo? Could you take a look at it if I create it?

Comment: I'd be happy to look at it. Two things. First, if I find something (code, etc.) that I think will help others by adding it to your question, I'll edit it in. Second, it will be about 14-16 hours before I'll get a chance to check it out. Post a link to your repo. Thanks.

Comment: @dfd no stress, thanks for your help: https://github.com/niklasgrewe/CalendarKit-iPadOS

Comment: Hmph. I downloaded your project, built it using Xcode 13, ran it on an iPad mini running iPadOS 15.0.1. Portrait, landscape, even split screen. Worked fine. I chose an iPad mini because of how it handles split screen. The only "quirk" I see is that - when your app is in compact mode (pretty much always in portrait split screen and only when your app is one-third in landscape) I get your screenshot **of the iPhone** but no way to show the secondary view. (Hope that makes sense, I don't use Calendar much.) I'm looking at a screenshot I'll add to your question.

Comment: thats because you're are using the UIHostingController Version of the CalendarView. Please uncomment Line 35 in SceneDelegate for using native CalendarViewController and try again. You' will see my layout issues...

Comment: Okay, why are you using `UIHostingController`? I may be missing something but that's used in SwiftUI, which you haven't tagged. I can show you how to simply use `UIKit` but it would involve changing `EventDetailView` into a `UIViewController`. If you are using SwiftUI, I'm probably wasting your time, sorry.

Comment: @dfd i only used `UIHostingController` because i couldn't find any other solution. If you know how I can fix the sidebar layout issues in UIKit, please show me. I have no idea...

Comment: @dfd i also found this: https://hacknicity.medium.com/the-primary-view-controller-is-wider-than-what-is-visible-on-screen-to-provide-extra-content-when-ed00ca003acf

Answer (score 1):

for all those who also face the problem: after some try and error i found a solution to fix the layout issue. In my case the key was to change views layout from `frame` to `autolayout` like this:

```swift
dayHeaderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
dayHeaderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
dayHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
dayHeaderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: headerHeight).isActive = true
```

you can find more information here:

[iOS 14 UISplitViewController: 5 Issues That You May Run Into](https://medium.com/swlh/ios-14-uisplitviewcontroller-5-issues-that-you-may-run-into-65b09601b3fb)